# Float Arguments and dict_values with NumPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

The main issue is that I'm being told by Python 3 that `dict_values` are being used as an argument while, apparently, a string or number is required. (Even though a float *is* a number, or so I thought.)

I have searched for various solutions to this problem and while I see aspects that seem to suggest what *might* be done, nothing just comes right out and says it in a way that I can generalize to my particulars.

The code is:

```
def get_features(self, state, action):
    q_state = np.array(SimpleExtractor().get_features(state, action).values()).astype(dtype=float)
    return q_state
```

That returns the following error when the code is executed:

```
float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict_values'
```

As per one of the suggested solutions, I tried to change the np line so that the dtype was indicated as such:

```
def get_features(self, state, action):
    q_state = np.array(SimpleExtractor().get_features(state, action).values(), dtype=float)
    return q_state
```

However that returns the exact same error.

I'm not sure if it matters but that `SimpleExtractor` that I'm calling is a large bit of code: [SimpleExtractor](https://github.com/testerstories/pacumen/blob/master/game/feature_extractors.py#L59)

I have some reason to believe that this particular bit of code, as written, would work on Python 2. But the particular project I'm on has been restructured to work with Python 3 and so I can no longer run it with Python 2 to test that out.

I think this may have to do with the fact of how the `features` variable is being returned from the `get_features` method in `SimpleExtractor`. But I'm not clear what I would do to get that into some form that my code above would accept.

I'm mainly just looking for insight into what I should do in this kind of situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert the `dict_values` object to list first so the array is created from the content of the list. NumPy cannot build an array of the contained items from `dict_values`, it instead creates an array of type object and puts the `dict_values` object inside:

```
>>> np.array(d.values())
array(dict_values([2, 4]), dtype=object)
```

What you're doing:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> d = {1: 2, 3: 4}
>>> np.array(d.values()).astype(float)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict_values'
```

---

What you should do:

```
>>> np.array(list(d.values())).astype(float)
array([ 2.,  4.])
```

---

```
q_state =  np.array(list(SimpleExtractor().get_features(state, action).values()))\
                                          .astype(dtype=float)
```