# networkx and dict_values causing float argument error

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I am trying to follow the tutorial given [here](https://aksakalli.github.io/2017/07/17/network-centrality-measures-and-their-visualization.html) code posted below for "reproducibility" but I get stuck when I try the draw() for the first visualization

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
def draw(G, pos, measures, measure_name):
    nodes = nx.draw_networkx_nodes
        (G, pos, node_size=250,cmap=plt.cm.plasma, 
        node_color=measures.values(),
        nodelist=measures.keys())
    nodes.set_norm(mcolors.SymLogNorm(linthresh=0.01, linscale=1))
    edges = nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos)
    plt.title(measure_name)
    plt.colorbar(nodes)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()
G = nx.karate_club_graph()
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
draw(G, pos, nx.degree_centrality(G), 'Degree Centrality')
```

The traceback keeps showing the error:
float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict_values'

based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45957968/float-arguments-and-dict-values-with-numpy?rq=1)

I think that it is a python 3 problem. I tried

```
draw(G, np.array(list(pos.values())).astype(float), 
nx.degree_centrality(G), 'Degree Centrality')
```

but I am still getting the same error.  Any advice?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I copied the tutorial and posted the code in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code works fine with python2.7.
The reason is the type of `measures.values()` which is different between Python 2 and 3.
Indeed, while in python 2.7 dict.values returns list, in python 3.x it returns a view of the dictionary’s values.

```
d={"k":"v"}
#python 2.7
type(d.values())  --->  <type 'list'>
#python 3.x
type(d.values())  --->  <class 'dict_values'>
```

Thus, you have a `TypeError` exception raised as `node_color` is expected to be a string or an array of floats and the argument has type `dict_values`. See the documentation [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.7/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_nodes.html) for more details.

To solve the problem you only need to change the way the node colors are passed to the `draw_networkx_nodes` function.
For instance, you could use a list as follows:

```
nodes = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=250, cmap=plt.cm.plasma, node_color=list(measures.values()),nodelist=measures.keys())
```

Comment: excellent! I couldn't figure out what was tripping it up! Thanks!