# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict_values',

Tags: python, typeerror, sigmoid

I was trying to plot the loss for my model, so coded like below, but I am getting below error:

> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict_values'

code:

```
def fit(self, X, Y, epochs=1, learning_rate=1, initialise=True, display_loss=False):

    #initialise w,b
    if initialise:
        self.w = np.random.randn(1,X.shape[1])
        self.b = 0

    if display_loss:
        loss = {}

    for i in tqdm_notebook(range(epochs), total=epochs, unit='epoch'):
        dw = 0
        db = 0
        for x,y in zip(X,Y,):
            dw += self.grad_w(x,y)
            db += self.grad_b(x,y)

        self.w -= learning_rate * dw
        self.b -= learning_rate * db

        if display_loss:
            Y_pred = self.sigmoid(self.perceptron(X))
            loss[i] = mean_squared_error(Y_pred, Y)

    if display_loss:
        plt.plot(loss.values())
        plt.xlabel('Epochs')
        plt.ylabel('Mean Squared Error')
        plt.show()

def predict(self, X):
    Y_pred = []
    for x in X:
        y_pred = self.sigmoid(self.perceptron(x))
        Y_pred.append(y_pred)
    return np.array(Y_pred)

sn = SigmoidNeuron()
sn.fit(X_scaled_train, Y_scaled_train, epochs=1000, learning_rate=0.01, display_loss=True)
```

Comment: Please post traceback which shows the line in error.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: As the error tells you, don't plot `loss.values()`...! `plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 9])` is the correct way to plot a list of squares. You probably want `plot(list(loss.keys()), list(loss.values()))`. But since your `loss` values are an ordered list, this is quite strange and you should probably use a `list` rather than a `dict` anyways.

Comment: it looks like you do `float(some_dictionary)` . **FULL** error message should show you which line makes problem so you should check what you have in variables in this line - ie. use `print()` , `print(type(...))`  - because it seems you use wrong values.

Comment: That’s certainly on line plt.plot(loss.values()). The first thing you could try is to convert to list: plt.plot(list(loss.values()))

Answer (score 5):

**TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict_values'**

> I got your error. This error occur if you are plotting the **loss.values** as it is...
>   which you shouldn't do it.

### You should change this dict_values to a list

> which creates an array of type object and puts the dict_values object inside:

<strike>plt.plot(loss.values())</strike>  instead of this you should use

**>`plt.plot(np.array(list(loss.values())).astype(float))`**

so your code should look like this:

```
    if display_loss:
        plt.plot(np.array(list(loss.values())).astype(float))
        plt.xlabel('Epochs')
        plt.ylabel('Mean Squared Error')
        plt.show()
```

so when you run the **fit function** or **invoke that function** with this
`sn.fit(X_scaled_train, Y_scaled_train, epochs=2000, learning_rate=0.015, display_loss=True)`

then you will get the loss plotting image as [loss_plotting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHAqL.png).

I took reference of this snippet
*[Float Arguments and dict_values with NumPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45957968/float-arguments-and-dict-values-with-numpy)*

Hope you get it...!